# Camera Application works on emulator but not real device (Alcatel 785 Smart 4 Mini) - java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed

Tags: android, camera, logcat

Android code for my main activity.

This works perfectly fine on my emulator but when I run this on my real device as stated (Alcatel 785 Smart 4 Mini) the application crashes.

The logcat will be provided as a comment.

Any help or guidance will appreciated.

```
package com.example.viewfinderee368;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

public class ViewfinderEE368 extends Activity {    
    private Preview mPreview;
    private DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide the window title.
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
        // Create our DrawOnTop view.
        mDrawOnTop = new DrawOnTop(this);
        mPreview = new Preview(this, mDrawOnTop);
        setContentView(mPreview);
        addContentView(mDrawOnTop, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class DrawOnTop extends View {
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Paint mPaintBlack;
    Paint mPaintYellow;
    Paint mPaintRed;
    Paint mPaintGreen;
    Paint mPaintBlue;
    byte[] mYUVData;
    int[] mRGBData;
    int mImageWidth, mImageHeight;
    int[] mRedHistogram;
    int[] mGreenHistogram;
    int[] mBlueHistogram;
    double[] mBinSquared;

    public DrawOnTop(Context context) {
        super(context);

        mPaintBlack = new Paint();
        mPaintBlack.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintBlack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaintBlack.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintYellow = new Paint();
        mPaintYellow.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintYellow.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mPaintYellow.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintRed = new Paint();
        mPaintRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintRed.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaintRed.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintGreen = new Paint();
        mPaintGreen.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintGreen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaintGreen.setTextSize(25);

        mPaintBlue = new Paint();
        mPaintBlue.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaintBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaintBlue.setTextSize(25);

        mBitmap = null;
        mYUVData = null;
        mRGBData = null;
        mRedHistogram = new int[256];
        mGreenHistogram = new int[256];
        mBlueHistogram = new int[256];
        mBinSquared = new double[256];
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            mBinSquared[bin] = ((double)bin) * bin;
        } // bin
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mBitmap != null)
        {
            int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
            int newImageWidth = canvasWidth;
            int newImageHeight = canvasHeight;
            int marginWidth = (canvasWidth - newImageWidth)/2;

            // Convert from YUV to RGB
            decodeYUV420SP(mRGBData, mYUVData, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);

            // Draw bitmap
            mBitmap.setPixels(mRGBData, 0, mImageWidth, 0, 0, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
            Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, mImageWidth, mImageHeight);
            Rect dst = new Rect(marginWidth, 0, 
                    canvasWidth-marginWidth, canvasHeight);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, src, dst, mPaintBlack);

            // Draw black borders                       
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, marginWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawRect(canvasWidth - marginWidth, 0, 
                    canvasWidth, canvasHeight, mPaintBlack);

            // Calculate histogram
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mRedHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 0);
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mGreenHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 1);
            calculateIntensityHistogram(mRGBData, mBlueHistogram, 
                    mImageWidth, mImageHeight, 2);

            // Calculate mean
            double imageRedMean = 0, imageGreenMean = 0, imageBlueMean = 0;
            double redHistogramSum = 0, greenHistogramSum = 0, blueHistogramSum = 0;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                imageRedMean += mRedHistogram[bin] * bin;
                redHistogramSum += mRedHistogram[bin];
                imageGreenMean += mGreenHistogram[bin] * bin;
                greenHistogramSum += mGreenHistogram[bin];
                imageBlueMean += mBlueHistogram[bin] * bin;
                blueHistogramSum += mBlueHistogram[bin];
            } // bin
            imageRedMean /= redHistogramSum;
            imageGreenMean /= greenHistogramSum;
            imageBlueMean /= blueHistogramSum;

            // Calculate second moment
            double imageRed2ndMoment = 0, imageGreen2ndMoment = 0, imageBlue2ndMoment = 0;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                imageRed2ndMoment += mRedHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                imageGreen2ndMoment += mGreenHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
                imageBlue2ndMoment += mBlueHistogram[bin] * mBinSquared[bin];
            } // bin
            imageRed2ndMoment /= redHistogramSum;
            imageGreen2ndMoment /= greenHistogramSum;
            imageBlue2ndMoment /= blueHistogramSum;
            double imageRedStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageRed2ndMoment - imageRedMean*imageRedMean );
            double imageGreenStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageGreen2ndMoment - imageGreenMean*imageGreenMean );
            double imageBlueStdDev = Math.sqrt( imageBlue2ndMoment - imageBlueMean*imageBlueMean );

            // Draw mean
            String imageMeanStr = "Mean (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenMean) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueMean);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10+1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10-1, 30+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageMeanStr, marginWidth+10, 30, mPaintYellow);

            // Draw standard deviation
            String imageStdDevStr = "Std Dev (R,G,B): " + String.format("%.4g", imageRedStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageGreenStdDev) + ", " + String.format("%.4g", imageBlueStdDev);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60-1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10+1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10-1, 60+1, mPaintBlack);
            canvas.drawText(imageStdDevStr, marginWidth+10, 60, mPaintYellow);

            // Draw red intensity histogram
            float barMaxHeight = 3000;
            float barWidth = ((float)newImageWidth) / 256;
            float barMarginHeight = 2;
            RectF barRect = new RectF();
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 200;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                float prob = (float)mRedHistogram[bin] / (float)redHistogramSum;
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - 
                    Math.min(80,prob*barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintRed);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin

            // Draw green intensity histogram
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight - 100;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mGreenHistogram[bin])/((float)greenHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintGreen);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin

            // Draw blue intensity histogram
            barRect.bottom = canvasHeight;
            barRect.left = marginWidth;
            barRect.right = barRect.left + barWidth;
            for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
            {
                barRect.top = barRect.bottom - Math.min(80, ((float)mBlueHistogram[bin])/((float)blueHistogramSum) * barMaxHeight) - barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlack);
                barRect.top += barMarginHeight;
                canvas.drawRect(barRect, mPaintBlue);
                barRect.left += barWidth;
                barRect.right += barWidth;
            } // bin
        } // end if statement

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    } // end onDraw method

    static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
            int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
                int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
                if (y < 0) y = 0;
                if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                    v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                    u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                }

                int y1192 = 1192 * y;
                int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
                int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
                int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

                if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;
                if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;
                if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;

                rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) & 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            }
        }
    }

    static public void decodeYUV420SPGrayscale(int[] rgb, byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height)
    {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        for (int pix = 0; pix < frameSize; pix++)
        {
            int pixVal = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[pix])) - 16;
            if (pixVal < 0) pixVal = 0;
            if (pixVal > 255) pixVal = 255;
            rgb[pix] = 0xff000000 | (pixVal << 16) | (pixVal << 8) | pixVal;
        } // pix
    }

    static public void calculateIntensityHistogram(int[] rgb, int[] histogram, int width, int height, int component)
    {
        for (int bin = 0; bin < 256; bin++)
        {
            histogram[bin] = 0;
        } // bin
        if (component == 0) // red
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 16) & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
        else if (component == 1) // green
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = (rgb[pix] >> 8) & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
        else // blue
        {
            for (int pix = 0; pix < width*height; pix += 3)
            {
                int pixVal = rgb[pix] & 0xff;
                histogram[ pixVal ]++;
            } // pix
        }
    }
} 

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    Camera mCamera;
    DrawOnTop mDrawOnTop;
    boolean mFinished;

    Preview(Context context, DrawOnTop drawOnTop) {
        super(context);

        mDrawOnTop = drawOnTop;
        mFinished = false;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
           mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

           // Preview callback used whenever new viewfinder frame is available
           mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
              public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
              {
                  if ( (mDrawOnTop == null) || mFinished )
                      return;

                  if (mDrawOnTop.mBitmap == null)
                  {
                      // Initialize the draw-on-top companion
                      Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth = params.getPreviewSize().width;
                      mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight = params.getPreviewSize().height;
                      mDrawOnTop.mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth, 
                              mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                      mDrawOnTop.mRGBData = new int[mDrawOnTop.mImageWidth * mDrawOnTop.mImageHeight]; 
                      mDrawOnTop.mYUVData = new byte[data.length];                    
                  }

                  // Pass YUV data to draw-on-top companion
                  System.arraycopy(data, 0, mDrawOnTop.mYUVData, 0, data.length);
                  mDrawOnTop.invalidate();
              }
           });
        } 
        catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        mFinished = true;
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
        // the preview.
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
        parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(15);
        parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

}
```

Comment: LOG CAT 

03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249): java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:2005)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at com.example.viewfinderee368.Preview.surfaceChanged(ViewfinderEE368.java:403)

Comment: 03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:628)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:88)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:183)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:680)

Comment: 03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4872)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)

Comment: 03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)

Comment: 03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: 03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:837)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:604)
03-11 17:33:47.926: E/AndroidRuntime(1249):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: try setting parameters in surfaceCreated() instead of surfaceChange() @taz gill

Comment: @Pooja Thanks for the help, however implementing this change gives no difference. The application is still crashing.

Answer (score 1):

Some line in the following sequence does not match your device capabilities:

```
parameters.setPreviewSize(320, 240);
parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(15);
parameters.setSceneMode(Camera.Parameters.SCENE_MODE_NIGHT);
parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
```

Often, there will be indication in logcat - not as part of your app's log, but for the system process that controls the camera.

Even if you cannot find hints there, you can eliminate the problem by checking the lines one by one (the exception happens not when you manipulate `Camera.Parameters`, but when you call `mCamera.setParameters()` with an illegal value somewhere.

You can check the parameters received from `mCamera.getParameters()` for supported preview sizes, frame rates, focus modes, and scenes.